# uWSGI is blocking connection to remote database

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, pymssql

My app is configured with flask's application factory.

So my app is structured like this:

```
-/app
--docker-compose.yml
--/server
---main.py
---server.ini(for wsgi)
---server.dockerfile
---/sweater
----__init__.py
----routes.py
--/nginx
---nginx.conf
---(other containers)
```

My main file:

```
from sweater import create_app

flask_app = create_app()
flask_app.app_context().push()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

My server.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = main.py
callable = flask_app
socket = :8080
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmpd-socket = 60
vacuum =true
die-n-term = true
```

my server.dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
#CMD python main.py
CMD ["uwsgi", "/app/server.ini"]
```

server/**init**.py:

```
import redis

from flask import Flask
from flask_assets import Environment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_user import UserManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
server_ip='10.104.4.95:8080'
database = 'LOGISTICS_DEV'
red = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, decode_responses=True)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")
    
    assets = Environment()
    assets.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        
        from sweater.models import User
        user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)
        user_manager.login_manager = login_manager

        @login_manager.user_loader
        def load_user(user_id):
            return User.query.get(user_id)
        
        from sweater.routes import portal
        app.register_blueprint(portal)
        
        from sweater.auth import auth
        app.register_blueprint(auth)
        
        from sweater.arm_analyst import arm
        app.register_blueprint(arm)
        
        from sweater.dashboards.routes import create_dash_instance
        app = create_dash_instance(app, server_ip)
        
        from sweater.dashboards import dash_bp
        app.register_blueprint(dash_bp)
    return app
```

and my docker-compose file is (full in case if some other container might be configured wrong):

```
version: '3.1'

volumes:
  base:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /srv/samba/anonymous/docker_new/base
  root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /srv/samba/anonymous/docker_new
services:
  flask:
    build:
      dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
      context: ./server
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Moscow
      FLASK_APP: flask_app
      APPLICATION_PORT: 8080
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: redis://redis:6379
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - base:/base
    depends_on:
      - redis
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - flask
  weekly_review:
    build:
      dockerfile: weekly_review.Dockerfile
      context: ./weekly_review
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /weekly_review
      - base:/base
  priemka_to_sql:
    build:
      dockerfile: priemka_to_sql.Dockerfile
      context: ./priemka_to_sql
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /priemka_to_sql
      - base:/base
  cargo:  
    build:
      dockerfile: cargo.Dockerfile
      context: ./cargo
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /cargo
      - base:/base
  orders:  
    build:
      dockerfile: orders.Dockerfile
      context: ./orders
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /orders
      - base:/base
  wrapping:  
    build:
      dockerfile: wrapping.Dockerfile
      context: ./wrapping
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /wrapping
      - base:/base
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  worker:
    build:
      context: ./celery_tasks
      dockerfile: celery.Dockerfile
    command: celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=4
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - flask
  monitor:
    build:
      context: ./celery_tasks
      dockerfile: celery.Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5555:5555"
    command:  ['celery', 'flower', '-A', 'tasks']
    environment:
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - worker
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  5;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

As u can see, in server.dockerfile i have a line "run main.py". When i run my app without wsgi and nginx everything works fine and i can astablish connection with database. But when i am trying to run everything with wsgi and nginx, i keep getting this error:

```
pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (20017, b'DB-Lib error message 20017, severity 9:
Unexpected EOF from the server (10.102.15.112)
DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
Adaptive Server connection failed (10.102.15.112)
DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
Adaptive Server connection failed (10.102.15.112)
')
```

i can't figure it out. Appreciate any help.